# How dual mode adapters USB to RS-485 or RS-422 distinguish between modes?

Tags: rs-232

There are many USB to RS-485 *AND* RS-422 adapters on Ebay, besides of RS-485 only  adapters.
And the former do not have any switch to select the mode. How do they know to work in half or full duplex mode, from which pair to receive?

To make this suitable for this forum, let me formulate it so: are single mode adapters (only 422 or only 485) more reliable than dual-mode ones?

Comment: The driver for the adapter can have all sorts of settings, no need for a physical switch. You should link some specific products to ask about so the question can be answered better.

Comment: Any adapter marked RS-485 only (one wire pair) vs. marked "RS-485 and RS-422" (two wire pairs)